# how to get an object from a string - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sending object friend through `params[:invitations][:friend]`. In my params looks like:`#< User:0x6925800>`. Can I convert this string to an object in my controller?

Why I am sending an object through params? Because I get it from a javascript function that triggers when a field in my dropdown menu is clicked. And if I try to send just an `Id(friend.id)` of my object rails gives me an error stack too deep.

I googled around but found nothing how to convert string to object so any answers would be greatly appreciated.

So my question remains how can I convert my string(of an object) to an actual object in my controller?

Comment: sending an entire serialized object through params is a really bad way to go, for lots of reasons - security for one, and it would also take a much longer string to serialize than you might think.  The solution is to pass the id, as you first tried.  If you paste your code that's causing the stack problem, I can help you fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I needed to use friend[:id] to retrieve my desired Id and avoid deep stack error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing you are asking about is called [serialization](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/object_serialization.html).

You can use it, but you shouldn't. Serialization may be good for caching purposes, but in most cases, if you need it - you do something wrong. Just pass an id to script and retrieve data again.

What you've got `#< User:0x6925800>` is not serialized object, it contains only class name and memory address, so it can't be unserialized.

Comment: Thanks for answering. True I needed to use friend[:id] to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to convert this to a real user instance. The reason is that this is a specific instance of User and does not persist between requests. I would go back and try and get it working with the User id.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I indeed did use the id now and it works! (friend[:id]).